# HP Proliant ML110 G7 - install nVidia GTX dual width PCIe GPU in case?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, nvidia-geforce, hp-proliant

I want to provide CUDA support for my HP Proliant server, but the case is only designed to support single width PCIe.

When searching for an answer, I spotted that a number of users had already benchmarked nVidia graphics card on this website http://www.userbenchmark.com/System/HP-ProLiant-ML110-G7/4272

Any idea how to install for example an GTX 1070 or 1060?

Comment: “Any idea how to install for example an GTX 1070 or 1060?” Purchase a low profile single width PCIe version of either card.

Comment: As above but the answer below also raises a very important concern: Power. The original PSU cannot cope with the demands of modern high-end Nivida cards. Hardly surprising because graphics performance is the least priority in server dedicated hardware.

Comment: An external case with a PCIe x1 to 4 off X16 expansion slots looks like the best current option. Would probably not provide the best gaming experience but should be fine for CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thermaltake (or chose another brand) PCIe riser came to my rescue. Although 200 mm  long, I carefully folded it multiple times into the case so my GTX card fitted under the lid. It wasn't possible to put the PCIe card holder back in, but the Thermaltake anti static bag provided insulation from the CPU heat sink. Power came from spare hard drive slots (2 drives in use, 2 spaces not) and the CD power. Note the most power hungry GPUs may not work in this configuration.

As I am using the GPU for Cuda I will probably buy another 2 or 3 GPUs and move them all to an external case and us a PCIe x1 to PCIe x16 extender, but for now I can test the nVidia docker tensorflow containers for a total cost of 130 (pounds in my case but you could do this for dollars or euros).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will be possible.  I looked at the spec sheet for this device:

[Proliant ML 110 G7 Datasheet](http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/press_kits/2011/poweryourdream/HP_ProLiant_ML110_G7_Datasheet.pdf)

And here are your problems:

- System only has 380W Power Supply
- Probably does not have any PCI 8-pin power connectors

I think you could be able to get an external graphics card into that system, but you need to think smaller, something that has a lower power supply requirement and doesn't have any power connectors.

Comment: In my case the GPU had a power adapter for HD 4 pin plugs so worked fine

Answer (score 0):

hi I think main problem is that Pc ie 16 slot (slot 1)  is adjacent side of case so any two slot size cards not usable-but *please anyone help here* as just what Iam facing with Pallit gtx1050Ti (does nt need connectors-but even if so adapters cheapily avaiable)

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: I put my interim solution on so you might be able to try it. Check power consumption though, not sure if the standard CPU is up to it.